# Graphic Design Stack Exchange AMA with UXPin, and you're all invited!

Tags: discussion

UXPin has offered to do an Ask Me Anything with us on Graphic Design SE. We of course are excited and want to make this a big success. You're all welcome to come join in on asking questions and participating.

For those unfamiliar with [UXpin](https://www.uxpin.com/)

> UXPin is a design tool you can use throughout the whole product creation process, including prototyping, collaboration, and handoff.
>
> You can use UXPin to create wireframes, UI designs, and interactive prototypes that feel like the real product. And all that without writing any code whatsoever. Your stakeholders can understand your ideas better and collaborate on iterations in one tool, which makes it easier to develop a real product.
>
> Since UXPin is cloud-based, you can work with it from browsers, but also at desktop apps on Windows, and macOS. This design tool is used by top companies of all sizes like Microsoft and PayPal, but also software houses and freelance designs

If you're interested, you can find links to the SE chatrooms we're running this on, and more details here on the [GD.SE meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/ama-with-uxpin-on-on-wednesday-october-2nd-4pm-6pm-gmt02)

JNat and the GDSE team are hoping it goes smoothly. If any mods are interested in helping to keep things organized on the day of (in the event we get a large turnout, and because I will be at my day job during it) please let me know.

Comment: Also folks - this is an event that one of the sites under SE's running with an organisation active in the industry in their scope.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek and its an app that's launched, and has real clients; which should be of interest to a good number of people on StackExchange in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because to me it looks like a product advertisement.  I think it's great that SE chat rooms are being used for discussion about a topic relevant to the scope of that site but to advertise it outside of chat rooms and user cards seems contrary to my understanding of advertising policies.

Comment: On the other hand - this is a site for the *network* as a whole, and an event run by *a site on the network* and this is literally the common space for the whole network. I edited in a description of what UXpin was cause It was unclear to me. As a moderator, I think this is a *perfectly* on label use of main meta.

Comment: @PolyGeo I suggest you read the [help] which states that this is on topic.

Comment: This is a textbook example of off-topic. Per-site metas exist for the very reason of being the place for site-specific announcements, discussions, and support. If every site was allowed to post their event advertisements here, we would be overrun.

Comment: I'm unclear where you are seeing that this is on-topic in the [help/on-topic] of this site unless it is the dot point which is a [Promotions & Advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) link.  The [Advertising](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising) link on that linked page just tells you how to purchase advertising on Stack Exchange sites.  Here you seem to be advertising for free.  I think what the Promotions & Advertising dot point says is on-topic is just discussion about SE promotions and advertising not making free advertising by any SE user to be on-topic.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not advertising anything. I'm a moderator that's been here longer than most members (and staff). I have zero affiliation with UXPin. Someone in Graphic Design asked a question about it and one of their employees answered it and offered to do an AMA. SE Staff is fully aware of it and encouraging it. I am not getting anything out of this but stress and extra work.

Comment: You appear to be advertising this company’s AMA. Your motivations for doing so are not being questioned.

Comment: I'm promoting an event for and on StackExchange. Something our members have regularly asked for is AMAs with professionals and companies for the software we use. This isn't for them, its for us. Do I hope they benefit as well? Of course. But make no mistake this is for us @PolyGeo

Comment: I think you should be using Community Ads to do this promotion. If other communities want to see it advertised then garnering six votes on each per site Meta that you post should be no problem.